# How to upload multiple jar which is generated by one pom into nexus repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I have one pom file where I have generated two jars based on the package, but I wanted to upload both the jars in the nexus repo. As i can see only one jar is copying to the nexus repo, not the other one.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>Shared</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.directory>.</project.build.directory>
    <localRepo>C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository1</localRepo>
</properties>



<build>
    <!--source directory pick the resources to be build. -->
    <sourceDirectory>source</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <!--maven compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--this plugin is to generate the manifest file -->
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.4</version> <configuration> <archive> <manifest> 
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> </manifest> <manifestEntries> <Built-By>my-org</Built-By> 
            </manifestEntries> </archive> </configuration> </plugin> -->
        <!-- this plugin to create the multiple jars with inclusion or exclusion 
            of the files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-Castor-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>

                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Built-By>my-org</Built-By>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/my/domain/BigDecimalHandler.class</include>
                            <include>com/my/domain/CalendarFieldHandler.class</include>

                            <include>com/my/domain/TimeZoneFieldHandler.class</include>

                        </includes>
                        <finalName>Castor-${version}</finalName>
                        <!-- <outputDirectory>${localRepo}/com/my/Castor/${version}/</outputDirectory> -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-Shared-jar</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>

                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Built-By>my-org</Built-By>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/my/domain/BigDecimalHandler.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/my/domain/CalendarFieldHandler.class</exclude>

                            <exclude>com/my/domain/TimeZoneFieldHandler.class</exclude>

                        </excludes>
                        <finalName>Shared-${version}</finalName>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>
</build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://nxrepository/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
```

Comment: Separate your code which means having different projects which solve the problem...BTW: Why do you change the defautl folder layout using `<sourceDirectory>...</sourceDirectory>`? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deploy:deploy-file` goal to deploy additional artifacts. But you should be aware that building two jars from one projects is against Maven standards. In your case, you would be better of defining two modules in your project which contain the different packages.